# Some websites rejecting HttpClient requests even with headers set

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have written some code to check to see if all websites in my database are still hosted and online.

The problem is some of these sites seem to have bot protection and whenever I try to request then via HttpClient they raise an error instead of displaying the page.

I have seen other similar questions that suggest to add in browser headers so I have done this but this does not help.  The same sites still reject the HttpClient connection but are perfectly fine when I view them in the browser.

Have I done something wrong with my code or do I need some additional steps?

Here is my code:

```
public static async Task CheckSite(string url, int id)
{
    try
    {
        using(var db = new PlaceDBContext())
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
        }))
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

            var rd = db.RootDomains.Find(id);
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            if (result != null && result.Length >= 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("fine");
                rd.LastCheckOnline = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was empty or short result");
                rd.LastCheckOnline = false;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        using(var db = new PlaceDBContext())
        {
            var rd = db.RootDomains.Find(id);
            rd.LastCheckOnline = false;
            db.SaveChanges();
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're setting your headers after you've sent your request.  You need to move your `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation` to be executed before `client.GetAsync()`

Comment: Set the headers before sending the request. You are doing them after already getting a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the headers before sending the request. You are doing them after already getting a response

```
public static async Task CheckSite(string url, int id) {
    try {
        using (var db = new PlaceDBContext())
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
        })) {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");

            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            using (var content = response.Content) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");

                var rd = db.RootDomains.Find(id);
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();


                if (result != null && result.Length >= 50) {
                    Console.WriteLine("fine");
                    rd.LastCheckOnline = true;
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was empty or short result");
                    rd.LastCheckOnline = false;
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        using (var db = new PlaceDBContext()) {
            var rd = db.RootDomains.Find(id);
            rd.LastCheckOnline = false;
            db.SaveChanges();
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

}
```